# Terraform template file escape bash variable for user data

Tags: bash, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

I have a pretty simple user data script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Create script that will be executed as cron
cat > generate_rds_password.sh <<EOF
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${region}

echo "Generating password"
export PGPASSWORD="$(aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname ${rds_host} --port 5432 --region ${region} --username ${pgusername})"
echo "$${PGPASSWORD}"
EOF

# Make it executable
chmod +x generate_rds_password.sh
```

What this does is create a script, and make it executable. It does some other things, but not relevant to the question.

The way I call generate this script with Terraform:

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "rds_bastion" {
  <...>
  user_data = base64encode(templatefile("${path.module}/bastion_userdata/startup.sh", {
    rds_host        = data.aws_db_instance.rds_instance[count.index].address
    pgusername      = var.pgmonitor_user
    region          = var.region
    environment     = var.environment
  }))
}
```

Now, for some reasons, I cannot echo the `$PGPASSWORD`.
The TF plan show me the correct command (`echo "${PGPASSWORD}"`), but when I cat the file from the instance, the echo is empty although the `PGPASSWORD` is correclty generated:

```
export PGPASSWORD="xxxx.asdsadsad.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/?Action=connect&DBUser=asdasd&X-Amz-Algorithm=...."
echo ""
```

What am I missing here?
From this [thread](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/escape-bash-variable-reference-in-terraform-template/31479), it seems to be the correct way?

Comment: Can you try to call your environment variable `TF_PGPASSWORD` and set a `variable "TF_PGPASSWORD" {}` block in your code please? Let me know if it worked :)

Comment: I don't think this is related to terraform @Will. This will be a script defined inside of the user data that is supposed to run on an EC2 instance. So what I would suggest is just removing the `export` in front of the `PGPASSWORD` and trying that.

Comment: I already tried removing the export part actually. Same result, that does not work...

Comment: But what I fail to understand is why create a shell script in order to create another shell script? Wouldn't it be easier to create only one?

Comment: @MarkoE - the reason is that the user_data script creates a script which will be called by a cron job. Further down in my code, I have ```echo "*/15 * * * * ec2-user generate_rds_password.sh >> /var/spool/cron/ec2-user"```

Comment: I'm guessing you have the `count` meta-argument defined for the `aws_launch_template` as well because you have a data source using `count.index`?

Comment: Correct indeed.

Comment: Ok, and since the assignment of the env var seems to be working, why do you need to echo it?

Comment: It's just a test, I'm using it after it to export it to SSM Parameter Store.  It seems I would need a `\$$` as per [here](https://faun.pub/terraform-ec2-userdata-and-variables-a25b3859118a). Testing that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after reading this [blog post](https://faun.pub/terraform-ec2-userdata-and-variables-a25b3859118a), it seems the variables are escaped differently if you create a script from a script.

What worked for me is a combination of `\$` and `\$$`

```bash
cat > generate_rds_password.sh <<EOF
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=${region}

echo "Generating password"
TF_PGPASSWORD="\$(aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname ${rds_host} --port 5432 --region ${region} --username ${pgusername})"
echo \$${TF_PGPASSWORD}
EOF
```